# How to convert Mathcad formula to WxMaxima

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima, mathcad

I'd like to convert a Mathcad formula to WxMaxima which calculates Fourier transform of two signals.

[image: Fourier1]

[image: Fourier2]

The problem is I haven't used Mathcad software until now. My primary operating system is Linux and as far as I know it is quite difficult to install Mathcad software in Linux.

So I decided to use WxMaxima and here is what I've tried so far.

```
N=8;
t=makelist(i,i,0,80);
A1=1;
A2=0;
A3=0.6;
y(t):=A1*sin((2*%pi*t)/(10*N)) + A2*sin((4*%pi*t)/(10*N)) + A3*sin((6*%pi*t)/(10*N));
wxplot2d ( [y(t)] , [t,0, 20] );
```

From the Mathcad formula t looks like a range. So I decided to use a list `t`.

`y(t)` function looks fine but when I try to plot this function using `wxplot2d` I get an error message about plotting range.

[image: wxmaxima error]

Any ideas about how to convert this Mathcad formula to WxMaxima?  Thanks.

Citation :

> Giovanni Schgör. [Segnali analogici e segnali numerici](http://www.schgor.com/ElabNumSegn/ENS01.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was that I didn't know about how to assign numerical values to variables.

Also I've learned how to plot discrete data using Maxima.

I should be able to get the result that I want with the changes below.

```
N:8;
t:makelist(i,i,0,80);
A1:1;
A2:0;
A3:0.6;
y(t):=A1*sin((2*%pi*t)/(10*N)) + A2*sin((4*%pi*t)/(10*N)) + A3*sin((6*%pi*t)/(10*N));
points:makelist([i/10,y(i)], i, 1, 80);
wxplot2d([discrete,points]);
```

[image: sen.png]